# Python error when trying to get dict item

Tags: python

I have `dict` in `python3` that look like this

```
{
    'id': '435633',
    'mysection': [
        {
            'myitem':
                {
                    'myitem' : 'testdata'
                }
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to print the value of `myitem` like this

```
print(mydict['mysection']['myItem']['myitem'])
```

But I get the error...

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not builtin_function_or_method
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `mydict['mysection']` is a list

Comment: mysection is a list containing a dictionary, so you need to access the 1st element of the list `mydict['mysection'][0]['myitem']['myitem']`

Answer (score 6):

`mydict['mysection']` is a list, not a dict

```
print(mydict['mysection'][0]['myitem']['myitem'])
```

output:

```
testdata
```

Answer (score 3):

`mydict['mysection']` is a list `[{'myitem': {'myitem' : 'testdata'}}]`

The first item `mydict['mysection'][0]` is a dictionary with your `myitem` in, so

```
print(mydict['mysection'][0]['myItem']['myitem'])
```

will work.

However, you maybe want to loop in case you end up with more than one item (or even no items)

Comment: Oh ok it was a list

Answer (score 0):

You can print all of dictionary object with loop.

```
for singleItem in mydict['mysection']:

    print(singleItem['myitem']['myitem'])
```